# How to use jquery.confirm plugin on dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-plugins

I've been looking at a few options for creating a confirm dialog for my web application, I decided to go with one that seemed to be good, which is 
[jquery.confirm](https://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/).

Its normal usage is:

```
$("selector").confirm({
    options / functions
});
```

My confirm dialog fires an ajax event and everything goes well, BUT, the ajax function changes the content of the page dynamically, and the confirm event does not work after the first ajax call.

Is there a way to call the confirm function from a

```
on("click", "selector", function(){
```

type of function?

I could copy my code, but it wouldn't matter very much, as the only thing I truly need is to fire this confirm plugin dialog from a dynamically generated element.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is there a way to call the confirm function from a `on("click", "selector", function(){` type of function ? ..... Try it !!

Comment: I did try, and it failed :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can do it this way:

```
$("#wrapper").on("click", ".removeNode", function () {

        $(this).confirm({

            confirm: function (button) {
                nodeTitle = button.parent().attr("id");
                if (nodeTitle) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "NodeManager/RemoveNode",
                        async: "true",
                        type: "GET",
                        data: { "title": nodeTitle },
                        success: function (result) {
                            $("#NodeViewer").html(result);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Only issue is, it requires 2 clicks to work, but it doesn't seem to be related to the "on" event.

Hope this helps someone else as well!

Comment: Sorry to reply to 3 year old issue but I am facing exactly this scenario that I must click twice, did you manage to resolve that ?

Comment: Ok i got it, I run the code you have provided right after I dynamically create those elements

Answer (score 1):

You can try using JqueryUI, which provide a similar function.

Comment: That was my next option, but I still wanted to know if there was a _js/jQuery_ syntax to call a plugin with the **on** function.